# Theme Menu vs Native Menu

Tags: menus

I installed

- the Blocksy Theme
- a Starter Site from Blocksy

Now, that starter site already comes with a Menu, like this:

[image]

But when I navigate to the native Customizer and go to Menus, it says there are no menus yet:

[image]

What is the relationship between native Wordpress Customizer Menues and Theme Menues? **Which one am I supposed to edit?** Should I create a new Menu here even though there is already one? I just wanted to edit the existing one ... but there exists none, or does there ... or what ?

Comment: "that starter site already comes with a Menu" - that is likely displaying the Pages (posts of the `page` type) on the site; which could happen when the theme calls `wp_nav_menu()` and there are no menus in the specified theme location - see the info regarding `fallback_cb` and `wp_page_menu()` [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_nav_menu/#more-information). So what the theme has is actually a theme location which by default displays the site's Pages. But have you checked the documentation for the themes in question?

Comment: @SallyCJ Oh okay, that helps. But do I need to create a menu using "Create New Menu" as well or is it enough that it implicitly uses the pages? I have [similar question][https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/406896/theme-pages-vs-native-pages] about pages.

Comment: "is it enough that it implicitly uses the pages" - that actually depends on you, but if you want to be able to easily edit the menu items via the admin UI, then you should create a custom menu and add the Pages to that menu. You can even add other items like Posts and Categories, if you want to. And what I was telling you, via my previous comment, is that the theme didn't actually provide a default menu, but a theme location that by default shows a menu containing the site's Pages. And to change that, yes, you'd need to create a custom menu which would replace that "default menu".